# Error when installing Visual Studio 2005 on Vista

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-vista, installation, 64-bit

I am getting the following error when trying to install Visual Studio 2005 on my 64bit, Vista computer:

> "1305.Error reading from file
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 8\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2005 Standard Edition -
>   ENU\SITSetup.dll"

I have successfully used the same DVD's to install Visual Studio on my old XP machine, and I can find the file (SITSetup.dll) on the DVD...and copy it off...so I don't think this is a case of having a bad DVD. At the time the error message pops up, I can see the file on my hard-drive, but it has a 0 size.

I've Googled this problem, and found some ideas, but nothing has worked thus far. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I've had similar problems with a copy of VS2005 standard for my XP computer.  I think it is an installer issue.  Thankfully the copy I had was a promo disk and not paid for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to confess on this..especially since someone voted for the question.

Everything I said in my original posting about using the disks successfully in the past -was true. However, after innumerable shots at trying to get this install to work, I finally went back and looked at the DVD, and found that either myself, or one of my kids, left traces of food stuck to the underside of the DVD. After cleaning the DVD off, the install worked fine. This is embarrassing.

I assumed the DVD was fine because I had used it before, as well as being able to copy files off it. However, the last time I used it was years ago, and sometime in between then and now...something got on it. I guess the lesson here is never skip the basic checks!

Comment: +1 for honesty. Although I was gonna say something as mundane as a media error. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it yesterday on my Vista box (32-bit, which may be the problem). It seemed to go through fine so I don't know what to tell you other than than when I first launched the app it notified me of "known compatibility issues" and recommended that I install both the SP1 and Vista SP! updates. No further issues past that.

As such, I would suspect either a problem with the 64 bit OS (though [Microsoft says it's fine...](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/Details.aspx?type=Software&p=Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%202005%20Standard&v=Microsoft&uid=8&pf=0&pi=5&c=Development%20Tools&sc=all&os=64-bit)) or other software on your machine. If you have a virus scanner running, for instance, disable it while installing.

Answer (score 0):

If your Vista machine is a guest running under VMware, try copying the entire DVD to your hard drive and install from there.

I don't know if the same random glitches occur on real machines.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is a problem for me on Windows 2008 Server while not on XP or Vista (all 32-bit). Not sure why there's any kind of issue here but it seems to be permissions related.

Also tried run as administrator etc but no luck.